# Advice To Improve Efficiency Of API Call And Cache

Tags: php

So i have the following code:

```
private function getArtistInfo($artist){
        $artisan = json_decode($artist, true);
        $artistObj = array();
        //fb($artist);
        $artistObj['id'] = $artisan['name']['ids']['nameId'];

        $memcache = new Memcached($artistObj['id']);
        $artistCache = $memcache->getMemcache();

        if($artistCache === false){

            $artistObj['name'] = $artisan['name']['name'];
            $artistObj['image'] = $artisan['name']['images'][0]['url'];

            $initArtist = array('id' => $artistObj['id'], 'name' => $artistObj['name'], 'image' => $artistObj['image']);

            $artistObj = $this->buildArtist($artisan, $artistObj);

                $memcache->setMemcache($artistObj);     

        }
        else{
            $initArtist = array('id' => $artistCache['id'], 'name' => $artistCache['name'], 'image' => $artistCache['image']);

        }
            return $initArtist;
    }
```

Now the code works but it takes getArtistInfo() too long to finish when i just want the $initArtist value; I would like my client to get right away the $initArtist once its constructed, and somehow let the caching of $artistObj runs in the background.

So far i have read up on several different topic i thought might be useful: event delegation, callback function, call_user_func, observer pattern, threading, gearman etc. However, I have no idea which one of them would actually do what i want. Please point me to the right direction.

EDIT:

My Memcached class:

```
 class Memcached {

    private static $MEMCACHED_HOST = "localhost";
    private static $MEMCACHED_PORT = "11211";

    private $id, $key, $memcache, $cacheOK;


    function __construct ($id){
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->key = 'artistID_'. $this->id;
        $this->memcache = new Memcache;
        $this->cacheOK = $this->memcache->connect(Memcached::$MEMCACHED_HOST, Memcached::$MEMCACHED_PORT);
    }

    protected function getMemcache(){
        $artistInfo = null;

        if($this->cacheOK === true){
            $artistInfo = $this->memcache->get($this->key);
        }

        if($artistInfo === false){
            return false;
        }

        return $artistInfo;

    }


    public function setMemcache($artistInfo){

        $this->memcache->set($this->key, $artistInfo, 0, 60);

    }

}
```

My buildArtist() code:

```
private function buildArtist($artisan, $artistObj){

        $artistObj['amgID'] = $artisan['name']['ids']['amgPopId'];


        $discography = $artisan['name']['discography'];

        foreach($discography as $album){
            $albumID = $album['ids']['amgPopId'];
            preg_match('/(\d+)/', $albumID, $matches);
            $albumObj['amgAlbumID'] = $matches[1];
            $albumObj['title'] = $album['title'];
            $albumObj['releaseDate'] = $album['year'];

            $albumObj['more'] = $this->getMoreMusic($albumObj['title'], $artistObj['name']);


            $artistObj['discography'][] = $albumObj;
        }
        return $artistObj;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not entirely clearly how long *too long* is, or which part of this code is what's slowing you down. For all we know, the slow part isn't the part that stores the data in Memcached.

In any case, once you do identify that this is your bottleneck, one thing you can do to accomplish this type of *out of order execution* is use a brokerless messaging queue like [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org) to accept JSON object that need cached. A separate PHP script can then take on the job of processing and caching these requests asynchronously outside of any web-request. This separate script could be run through a cron-job or some other job manager that handles the caching part in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [`set`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.set.php) and [`get`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.get.php) rather than using the memcache persistence ID, i'm not even sure what `setMemcache` and `getMemcache` are but they aren't in the extension documentation.

Here's an example from the documentation:

```
<?php
$m = new Memcached();
$m->addServer('localhost', 11211);

if (!($ip = $m->get('ip_block'))) {
    if ($m->getResultCode() == Memcached::RES_NOTFOUND) {
        $ip = array();
        $m->set('ip_block', $ip);
    } else {
        /* log error */
        /* ...       */
    }
}
```

Please show the code of `buildArtist` for help on optimizing it.

Comment: Thanks for your help Martin. 

Please see my edits. 

Currently it takes getArtistInfo() almost 15seconds to finish execution :(

Comment: @twiart we need to see getMoreMusic next ;) ... It looks like running that query in your loop is causing the problem. If you could use a `JOIN` to get all of the music in one query that would likely solve your problem

Comment: thanks for your reply. getMoreMusic() is indeed the bottleneck ;it is another function to call api with more loops in it. By JOIN, do you mean the implode() function kinda join? Is there a way to run things like api in batch? Perhaps what i'd like to know is what are the best practices when making multiple api calls in one go..?

Comment: The top level calls don't do anything much - they aren't an issue. I meant an SQL join - I'm assuming your data all comes from a database of some kind. If you can pull all of the artists music in one query, it'd save you doing it in a loop and drastically improve performance.